# Optimization of calculating recommendations and work with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, performance

I have two models `User` and `Brand`, and Many-to-Many relationship between them (through `UserBrand` table). I have about a thousand users, a thousand brands and a hundred favorite brands of each user.

```
User.all.count # => 1000
Brand.all.count # => 1000
User.find(1).brands # => 100
```

If I'd like to find 5 users, which favorite brands almost equal to current users', I wrote the following in the User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_brands
  has_many :brands, :through => :user_brands

  def similar_users
    result = {}

    User.all.each do |u|
        result[u] = shared_brands_with u.brands
    end

    result.sort{ |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }[1..5].map!{ |e| e[0] }
  end

  def shared_brands_with(brands)
    (brands & @brands).size
  end
end
```

and the following in the `users/show` view

```
<h2>Similar users</h2>
<ul>
  <% @user.similar_users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= link_to user.name, user %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

But it takes about 30-60 seconds to see user recommendations in the browser.

So my question is "How can I speed up calculation of recommendations?"

**UPD:** using

```
    User.includes(:brands).each do |u|
        result[u] = shared_brands_with u.brands
    end
```

doubles performance, but even with 50 brands instead of 100, giving recommendation in 10 sec is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically. You're pulling the whole users table. And for each, grabbing the brands list for that user, and presumably the brands themselves. And filtering. I wouldn't exect it to be fast. :-)

You're going to need to rewrite that logic in SQL to make it fast. Sorry I'm not more fluent than at in ruby - can't really make sense of the criteria... But in essence, fetch the brands through a single query.

It'll be big and ugly, full of joins and in() and possibly group by/having clauses, but it'll be faster than your current approach.

Comment: Can you help with those SQL's? I'm not fluent at SQL-queries.
There are three tables:
**User** with fields __id__, __name__; 
**Brand** with __id__ and __name__; 
**UserBrand** with __id__, __user_id__ and __brand_id__